# PDF Editor Software with Annotations and Custom UI?

Tags: pdf, web-development, web-browser, pdf-viewer, angular

I am looking for a good PDF editor with annotation features (comments and pen tool) as well as the ability to pick and choose features (because I don't want them to have a download button or a print button). Does anyone have good suggestions? It doesn't matter the cost because I am just using it for a market research paper! Ideally it would be compatible with Angular.

Comment: You are looking for an application? Or a SDK/library? why is hiding the print/download button important?

Comment: @Ryan I want to limit the the ability to steal/copy the pdfs. I think I want a SDK/library that will embed in my already existing angular component

Comment: @Ryan viewers I have already considered are PDFtron, PSPDFKit, Qoppa Software, and LeadTools

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "considered"? Why did you not pick one of those four solutions?

Comment: @Ryan all those options are valid, and we are leaning towards PDFtron, but part of my job is I have to prove why all the other PDF editors are not as good as the best option, and I want to make sure I have all of the available options

Comment: Note PDFTron offers full pre-sales support, so I would encourage you to reach out to PDFTron support to get a solution engineer. They can save you a lot of time in evaluating PDFTron SDK.